# PROBLEM: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type

Tags: csv, google-colaboratory

#CODE:

from google.colab import files

load=files.upload()

#OUTPUT:

CELSIUS.csv(text/csv) - 263 bytes, last modified: 27/8/2022 - 100% done

Saving CELSIUS.csv to CELSIUS.csv.

#CODE:

df=pd.read_csv(load["CELSIUS.csv"])

#OUTPUT:

OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type